# Error "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate"

Tags: netbeans, maven

Estoy intentando crear un proyecto Maven Enterprise Application (ear) en Apache Netbeans 13, entro a las opciones para crear un nuevo proyecto y elijo Java with Maven -> Enterprise Application, escribo el nombre despues elijo la versión de Jakarta EE 9 y presiono el botón finish. Todo parece iniciar bien, sin embargo me sale un error justo antes de terminar de crearse el proyecto:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Estoy usando Apache Maven 13, JDK 8 u321 y Maven 3.8.5.
Alguien sabe que podría estar saliendo mal o que me hace falta para poder crear el proyecto?

Añado el contenido del pom.xml que se genera:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.prueba.ear</groupId>
    <artifactId>prueba-ear</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>prueba-ear-1.0</name>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>9.0.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: por tu pom.xml para saber el tipo de paquete que definiste

Comment: ya lo he puesto, aunque no se de que vaya a servir ya que desde un inicio sé que está mal, porque yo definí un packaging ear y en el pom se crea como war

Comment: El problema que le veo es que tu maven es tres, pero tanto en tu schema como en tu modelo defines la version 4. Si eso no funcionara te recomiendo darle una leida a https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/deploying_into_a_web_server/buildwar-modify